# Parse data from Excel in the same column but different rows?

Tags: python, excel, parsing, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with a list of contact info all in one column, but each type of contact info is separated into different rows. The number of types of contact info differ between each person. The data looks like this: [example of text data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9HPw.png)

I need to move all of the information listed as "position", "phone", "mobile phone", and "email" to their own subsequent columns, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I'm not sure if there's a way to do it in Excel directly, so I am open to ideas using Python. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Excel I would suggest using Power Query or VBA. Give it a try and post back with your results.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML(CONCAT("<a><b>1",IF($A$2:$A$27="","</b><b>","<c>"&$A$2:$A$27&"</c>"),"</b></a>"),"a/b["&ROW(A2)&"]/c"&IF($B$1=B$1,"[1]","[contains(.,'"&B$1&"')]")),B$1&":",),"")
```

This is for your reference only.

Comment: Hm, the only issue is that it doesn't follow along with their names and stay within the newspaper they work for. Think there's a way to go around that?

Comment: The answer has changed.